# How to resolve the undefined symbol error on an AIX machine when trying to compile c program?

Tags: c, ibm-mq, aix, mq

Following is the error obtained on compiling the code

```
$ cc -o mq mq.c
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .MQCONN
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

mqconn function is defined in header file cmqc.h and the header file is included in mq.c file

How to resolve this error which is related to linking of file?

Comment: Defined or just *declared*? There is a very important difference between those two..

Comment: You need to link against the library/object-file containing the definition/implementation of what is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the response .yes the function is just declared.

Comment: Question is  do i have to look at the mapfile (obtained from the bloadmap) to link the required library/object-file .

Comment: You should find out what libraries have been delivered with MQS (aka Websphere MQ)

Comment: OK now if I have the libraries delivered .how do I link them to the source code during compilation ?

Comment: Please read some basic c-programming howto... Example `gcc -o myprog myprog.c -L/opt/product/lib -lproduct -L/somepath/lib -lsomelib`

Comment: You can find full instructions for building an MQ C application on AIX here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q028350_.htm

Answer (score 1):

The fact that a function *prototype* is defined in a header file doesn't mean the function is defined in the header file. You're missing the library / object file which implements the functions prototyped in `cmqc.h`

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Please read the MQ Knowledge Center as it has a whole section on compiling MQ applications for AIX.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q028350_.htm